# Regex for validating a website address in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, validation

When I use a regex validator on a page with the following regular expression:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexWebsiteValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ctlWS" ValidationExpression="(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?" ErrorMessage="Invalid Website Address!" />
```

and enter `http://www,google.com` in the textbox,
the validation fails as expected.

If I use the same regex but try to match it using Regex.Match, it passes. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
string strRegex = @"(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?";
bool b = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("http://www,google.com", strRegex).Success;
```

b is `true`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, you are not anchoring your expression using `^(regex goes here)$`. What is happening here is that it is successfully matching the "google.com" part. The *RegularExpressionValidator* control probably adds these anchors implicitly—I don't know offhand because I never use the things.

In order to help you debug this further, make use of the `Match.Value` property so you can see exactly what is being matched.

More importantly, though, **don't use regular expressions to validate URLs**. There is a `Uri` class in .NET already. Use it's `Parse` method.

Comment: Wow, this worked! Can you explain anchoring the expression using `^(myregex)$`?

Comment: `^` and `$` are regular expression "anchors". `^` matches the start of the input, while `$` matches the end. I recommend www.regular-expressions.info for learning more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Regex expert by any stretch of the imagination but it doesn't look like you're escaping the slashes in your strRegex variable as you've got the @ sign at the beginning of the declaration

Try something like :

```
string strRegex = @"(http(s)?://)?([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+(/[\\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?";
```

Comment: The `@` prefix causes the string to be interpreted literally. Backslashes are no longer interpreted as escape sequences.